# Macro for Outllook to execute Alt+R,KA,K

Tags: vba, outlook

I use Outlook 2016 and want to create a macro to send the following Keystrokes (or commands) to Outlook.
It should navigate in Outlook to Menu "Start" -> then "Open Calendar" then "From Adressbook). In German this is the combination Alt+r,KA,A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the following macro (don't know if this is dependant on the language of Outlook, I use Outlook 2016 / 365 in german language)

```
Sub openCalendar()
SendKeys "^2", True
SendKeys "%", True
SendKeys "{R}", True
SendKeys "{1}", True
SendKeys "KA", True
SendKeys "A", True
End Sub
```

I learned that you cannot send R1 (which Outlook displays) ... but you can send R and 1 separately. works great.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [SendKeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sendkeys-statement) function available in VBA. For example:

```
SendKeys "%{r}", True
```

It sends the Alt+r.

Each key is represented by one or more characters. To specify a single keyboard character, use the character itself. For example, to represent the letter A, use "A" for string. To represent more than one character, append each additional character to the one preceding it. To represent the letters A, B, and C, use "ABC" for string.

The plus sign (+), caret (^), percent sign (%), tilde (~), and parentheses ( ) have special meanings to SendKeys. To specify one of these characters, enclose it within braces ({}). For example, to specify the plus sign, use {+}.